# Not able to add Title bar for Listview

Tags: android, listview, titlebar

The requirement for my screen is like having a title bar at the top middle and followed by the list view when am trying to do that am not able to do like i got state name in every list item.I want that only in the top and once. And the screen shot of it is
[image: screen shot]

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>     <TableLayout
>       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         >
>       <TableRow>
>       <TextView 
>          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>          android:background="#000000"
>          android:text="Select State"
>                 
>       ></TextView>
>       </TableRow>
>       <TableRow> 
>       <TextView  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>           
>            android:id="@+id/label"
>           android:textSize="30px"></TextView>
>     </TableRow>
>     </TableLayout>
> ```

I have tried many ways this is my present layout

and my java code is

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class new21 extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // Create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity
        String[] names = new String[] { "Andhra Pradesh", "Kerala","Tamilnadu","Karnataka" };
        // Use your own layout and point the adapter to the UI elements which
        // contains the label
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.new21,
                R.id.label, names));
    }

    @Override
    
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // Get the item that was clicked
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String keyword = o.toString();
        if(keyword.equals("Andhra Pradesh"))
        {
            Intent ima45=new Intent(new21.this,new31.class);
            startActivity(ima45);
    
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: " + keyword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        
    }

}
```

Can any one help me.

Comment: please update your new21.xml entire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can addHeader to the ListView like this,

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.addHeaderView(header);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, names));
```

Where `R.layout.header` is the layout that contains a `TextView` with text `"Select State"`

**UPDATED:**

```
public class ListViewProblemActivity extends ListActivity {

    ListView listView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // Create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity
        String[] names = new String[] { "Andhra Pradesh", "Kerala","Tamilnadu","Karnataka" };
        // Use your own layout and point the adapter to the UI elements which
        // contains the label

        TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tv.setText("Select State");

        listView = getListView();
        listView.addHeaderView(tv);
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,names));
    }

    @Override

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // Get the item that was clicked

        if(position != 0){
            System.out.println(position - 1);
            Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position - 1);
            String keyword = o.toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: " + keyword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usey only a `ListView` in your activity, remove the heading there. Then use `ListView.addHeaderViwe();` to add a header to the Listview. This Header is display before the first item.
See the [documentaton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing fully wrong. Just take a LinearLayout with one TextView (for Title bar) and ListView (To display listview), nothing more than these 2 views.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <TextView 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:background="#000000"
         android:text="Select State">
      </TextView>

      <ListView 
         android:id="@+id/lviewState"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent">
      </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, follow your code to display ListView.

Answer (score 0):

you better use ListView.addHeaderViwe();

but don't forget to remove what u did "extends ListActivity", no need for that,

and also remove title from your "new21.xml" 
in your xml, just fix the text item u want to show in every row of the list,